# .fill() equivalent for Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've tried googling this with terms such as "fill equivalent for objects" but it insists on only showing me results for Arrays (which makes sense, since this is an [array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)).

I know if it were an array, I could just do `array.fill(0, 0, 28)`;

However, I want to fill an object with a predetermined amount of keys. I could use a loop like;

```
let dateObj = {};
for(let i; i < 31; i++){
  // fill a key in my object with dateObj.i = ''
}
```

to do this, but wondered if there's an easier way.

My current object looks like this;

```
04-Apr-19: (40) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
05-Apr-19: [{…}]
```

Essentially, I want to use it for filling a Graph for the last 30 days. However, as you can see, it only contains data for two days. I therefore need to fill the other 28/29 days.

Any ideas or will I just have to use a loop?

Comment: No, there is not. It's a very uncommon case, so there's no pre-built function for it. Keep using a for loop

Comment: A set number of keys, but what should the values be prefilled as - null?

Comment: @Utkanos - Anything really, I just need those keys to take up space in the graph.

Comment: @CristianTraìna Thanks, that's fair. I'll see if I can change my data to be an array full of objects, work around it.

Comment: What should be the key names?

Comment: @adiga For now, anything. I can work on making them fit in to my dataset later. It's the 'length' of the object I'm going for at the moment.

Comment: `{ ...Array.from({ length: 30 }) }` gives you an object with 30 numerical keys starting from 0. You are expecting something like this?

Comment: If your property names are integer indices, why are you not using an array?

Comment: @Bergi I planned to eventually make them dates at some point in the future

Comment: Your question is unclear. IIUC, you'll get an object which has some dates as keys. You want to fill in the rest of them. Not sure what this has to do with numerical keys. @JaromandaX's answer looks promising though

Comment: @adiga - I apologise if it's unclear. Essentially, I just want to make sure that I always have 30 keys in an object, even if only 2 results are returned from a database. The idea is that each key will be represented as a day in a graph. Without making sure I have the right number of keys, they do not take up the correct proportions when rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little thing I just whipped up

```js
let obj = {
  '04-Apr-2019': [1, 2, 3],
  '05-Apr-2019': [4, 5, 6]
};
const fillMonth = (obj) => {
  // fix this - it may not be fully cross browser compatible
  let d = new Date(Object.keys(obj)[0].replace(/-/g, '/'));
  let year = d.getFullYear();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
  d.setDate(0);
  let last = d.getDate();
  let txtMonth = d.toLocaleDateString('en', {month:'short'});
  return Array.from({
    length: last
  }, (_, i) => ({
    [`${(i+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${txtMonth}-${year}`]: null
  }));
};
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...fillMonth(obj), obj);
console.log(newObj);
```

Though, it does rely on having at least ONE key

I'm assuming you want to "fill" a month of keys

most of this code is just to create the "nn-mmm-yyyy" keys for a full month, with null value

then, the trick is, and the core of the answer:

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, ...fillMonth(obj), obj);
```

use Object.assign to do the heavy lifting for you, first, all the keys for every day of the month are added `...fillMonth(obj)`, then the original object is added, overwriting any keys with the values from `obj`

The rest of the code is really just a quick hack to read the first key, get a date from it, calculate how many days are in that month, and produce an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native function build into the language which does it. However, you can very easily build your own function for it.

Without a loop:

```js
const fillObject = (number, seed = {}, startIndex = 0) => new Array(number).
    fill('').
    reduce((acc, _, i) => Object.assign(acc, {[i + startIndex]: _}), seed);

console.log(fillObject(28));
console.log(fillObject(26, {'0': '', '1': ''}, 2))
```

With a loop:

```js
const fillObject = (number, seed = {}, startIndex = 0) => {
  const acc = seed;
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i += 1) {
    acc[i + startIndex] = '';
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(fillObject(28));
console.log(fillObject(26, {'0': '', '1': ''}, 2))
```

Comment: Nice, I could work with this. I might need to ask this as a separate question, but what would happen if I have an object that already has 2 of the keys populated, like the example in my question, and I just needed to fill the rest?

Comment: You'd need to pass in the starting object which you want to have filled. I'll update my answer

Comment: Updated the code to allow to create the object entirely or from a starting object.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I did upvote this answer - however Jaromanda X's was a little closer to what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Lewis No probs, glad you have a solution. Thanks for the upvote! :)